# PhoneGap - Resetting Plugins due to Page Load

Tags: ios, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I am facing an problem in phonegap while integrating native EmailComposer.

MailComposer should open up on button click, but it does not shows the mailComposer for IOS, same code for android is working,

My Code is as follow:

```
        <html>
        <head>
            <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="emailcomposer.js"></script>

            <script type="text/javascript">
            document.addEventListener("deviceready", deviceready, true);
            function deviceready() {
                console.log("Device ready");
            }.
            //function to send mail using mail composer
            function composeText(){
var vehiclemileage = document.getElementById('vehiclemileage').value;
var vehiclemodel = document.getElementById('vehiclemodel').value;
var message1 = document.getElementById('message_body').value;
var vechicleyear = document.getElementById("yeardropdown");
var strUser = vechicleyear.options[vechicleyear.selectedIndex].value;
var vehiclemake = document.getElementById("vehiclemake");
var makevehicle = vehiclemake.options[vehiclemake.selectedIndex].value;

var deviceName = device.platform;
var devicemodel = device.model;


if(vehiclemodel == '' || makevehicle == ''){
alert("Please Enter all the Value");

 navigator.notification.alert(
        'Please Enter all the Value', // message
        alertDismissed,              // callback
        'Vehicle and Model',        // title
        'Ok'                       // buttonName
    );
 }
else
{
            //function to check folder named "RepairMyCar" and extract picture from folder to attach it to mail
                var attachPath; 
                var attachFile= new Array();
                window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, function(fileSystem) {
                    fileSystem.root.getDirectory("RepairMyCar", {
                        create: true
                    }, 
        function(directory) {
            console.log("Final 63" + directory.fullPath);
            attachPaths = directory.fullPath;
            var attachPath=attachPaths.slice(7,attachPaths.length);
            var directoryReader = directory.createReader();
            directoryReader.readEntries(function(entries) {
                var i;
                for (i=0; i<entries.length; i++) {
                    console.log(entries[i].name);
attachFile[i] =attachPath + "/" + entries[i].name;
                            }
                            console.log(attachFile);
                        }, 
                        function (error) {
                            alert(error.code);
                        });

                    });
                }, function(error) {
                    alert("can't even get the file system: " + error.code);
                });
                var dated, fnamed, phoned, emailed;
                 if(typeof(Storage)!=="undefined")
{
 dated = localStorage.date;
 fnamed = localStorage.fname;
 phoned = localStorage.phone;
 emailed= localStorage.email;
}

                console.log(attachFile);
                var newattachment = attachFile.toString();
                //Open mail composer with all datas
 setTimeout(function(){window.plugins.emailComposer.showEmailComposerWithCallback(null,
                    "Get an Estimate",
                     "Date: " + dated + '<br>' + "First Name: " + fnamed +  '<br>' + "Phone Number: " + phoned +  '<br>' + "Email Address: " + emailed +   '<br>' + "Year of Vehicle: " + strUser +  '<br>' + "Make of Vehicle: " + makevehicle +  '<br>' +  "Model of Vehicle: " + " " + vehiclemodel + '<br>' + 
                     "Mileage of Vehicle: " + " " + vehiclemileage + '<br>' +  message1 + '<br>' + "Sent from My:" + deviceName + devicemodel,
                [sth@sth.com],
                    [],
                    [],
                    true,
                    attachFile
                    );},100);
                //Clear LoccalStorage
                localStorage.clear();
            //exit the app after clicking this button
            navigator.app.exitApp();
            // navigator.camera.cleanup(onSuccess,fail);
            // function onSuccess(){
            // }
            // function fail(){
            // }
        }
}
        function onFail(message) {
            alert('Failed because: ' + message);
        }

    /***********************************************
    * Drop Down Date select script- by JavaScriptKit.com
    * This notice MUST stay intact for use
    * Visit JavaScript Kit at http://www.javascriptkit.com/ for this script and more
    ***********************************************/
    //function to  load year in drodown. Default selected year : Current Year
    function populatedropdown(yearfield){
        var today=new Date()
        var yearfield=document.getElementById(yearfield)
        for (var i=0; i<31; i++)
            //Select Year
    var thisyear=today.getFullYear()
    for (var y=0; y<25; y++){
        yearfield.options[y]=new Option(thisyear, thisyear)
        thisyear-=1
    }
    yearfield.options[0]=new Option(today.getFullYear(), today.getFullYear(), true, true) //select today's year
    }
    </script>

    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="wrapper">
            <h1>Get a Repair Estimate</h1>
            <div class="main-content">
    <p>
                Please Enter the Year, Make, Model and Mileage of Your Vehicle and any other information we should know.
                </p>
                <form class="vehicle-detail-form">
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <label>Year of Vehicle: </label>
                        <form action="" name="someform">
                        <select id="yeardropdown">
                        </select> 
                    </form>

                    <script type="text/javascript">

    //populatedropdown(id_of_day_select, id_of_month_select, id_of_year_select)
    window.onload=function(){
        populatedropdown("yeardropdown")
    }
    </script>
                    </li>
                    <!-- Vehicle Year Selection -->

    <li><label>Model of Vehicle:</label>
    <input type="text" name="vehiclemodel" id = "vehiclemodel">
    </li>
    <li><label>Mileage of Vehicle:</label>
    <input type="number" name="vehiclemileage" id = "vehiclemileage"></li>
    <li>
        <textarea  name="message_body" id = 'message_body'  placeholder="Add Notes here(if any)"></textarea>
    </li>
    </form>
    <div style="clear:both;"></div>
    <div class="large-button-wrapper">
    <button onclick="composeText();">Get Your Estimate</button>
    </div>  
    </div>
    </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

I have kept EmailComposer.h and EmailComposer.m in plugin folder as stated in [this link](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/iPhone)

Answer (score 1):

I found a workaround if you work on an iOS project. I have the same issue.

After view change in backbone router `console.log` stops working in Xcode you can use Safari Web Inspector on your Mac. Every `console.log` is visible there.